# mysql connector c++ install on raspberryPi

Tags: c++, mysql, installation, raspberry-pi

I want to setup connector/c++ on my raspberry Pi to access a mysql db. At first I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

which installed successfully, but the I got the error:

```
ERR: MySQL_Connection::setReadOnly() (MySQL error code: 0, SQLState:  )
```

which comes with the version of cppconn I'm using, as its said here: [MySQL Connector for C++ | MySQL_Connection::setReadOnly() exception on setSchema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462633/mysql-connector-for-c-mysql-connectionsetreadonly-exception-on-setschema)

And when I checked:

```
sudo apt-cache show libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

it said "version: 1.1.0-4"

So then I tried to install the latest package from source:
https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/ which was under ->Source Code -> Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive

I downloaded it and did "tar xvzf mysql-...." and everything worked. But when I tried to build it with

```
cmake .
```

I got the error:

```
CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

/home/pi/quadro/mysql-connector/CMakeLists.txt:114:24

Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
  This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  Syntax Warning in cmake code at

/home/pi/quadro/mysql-connector/CMakeLists.txt:114:54

Argument not separated from preceding token by whitespace.
  This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- mysql_config was found /etc/mysql
CMake Error at FindMySQL.cm:165 (MESSAGE):
  mysql_config wasn't found, -DMYSQL_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE=...
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (INCLUDE)


CMake Error at FindMySQL.cm:167 (MESSAGE):
  Cannot find MySQL.  Include dir: MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND library dir:
  cxxflags:
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:55 (INCLUDE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/pi/quadro/mysql-connector/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

I know it means, it cant find the mysql_config, but neither do I know how to tell it where the file is, nor where the file actually is.

So please help me. I'm so sick of this.

Thanks alot.

EDIT:

I tried to install the latest packages manually, which I downloaded from:

https://packages.debian.org/jessie/armhf/libmysqlcppconn-dev/download

```
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlcppconn7_1.1.3-6_armhf.deb
sudo dpkg -i libmysqlcppconn-dev_1.1.3-6_armhf.deb
```

And now I get:

```
$ sudo apt-cache show libmysqlcppconn-dev
Package: libmysqlcppconn-dev
Status: install ok installed
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Installed-Size: 3213
Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-    maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Architecture: armhf
Source: mysql-connector-c++
Version: 1.1.3-6
Depends: libboost-dev, libmysqlcppconn7 (= 1.1.3-6)
Description: MySQL Connector for C++ (development files)
 MySQL Connector/C++ is a MySQL database connector for C++.
 .
 It mimics the JDBC 4.0 API.
 .
 This package contains the development files (headers, static library).

Package: libmysqlcppconn-dev
Source: mysql-connector-c++
Version: 1.1.0-4
Architecture: armhf
Maintainer: Debian MySQL Maintainers <pkg-mysql-    maint@lists.alioth.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 3382
Depends: libboost-dev, libmysqlcppconn5 (= 1.1.0-4)
Homepage: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Connector_C++
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Filename: pool/main/m/mysql-connector-c++/libmysqlcppconn-dev_1.1.0-    4_armhf.deb
Size: 602550
SHA256: 286b6bf2ef3eb05dc8660a31780dd9af65c06f7d0d675257636281b2de056e15
SHA1: e53eeb1cf70c7522f557bbb6cbf0a753c6788fbb
MD5sum: 8770d029c21d086a48279c1f6e92f4a6
Description: MySQL Connector for C++ (development files)
 MySQL Connector/C++ is a MySQL database connector for C++.
 .
 It mimics the JDBC 4.0 API.
 .
 This package contains the development files (headers, static library).
```

Is this good or bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the MySQL client library development files:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

An easier way to try and ensure you have all dependencies installed, is to ask apt to install all build dependencies for it's packaged version:

```
apt-get build-dep libmysqlcppconn-dev
```

Comment: yeah, I already installed the libmysqlclient-dev, but it didn't work. And I dont think 'apt-get build-dep libmysqlcppconn-dev' will work better, because, the latest version of cppconn-dev I get from 'apt-get' is the buggy version 1.1.0-4 and not the newer version 1.1.5 I need. But thanks so far

Answer (score 0):

The `libmysqlclient-dev` package doesn't exist anymore. I guess it was renamed. So to install the c++ connector there is this new package:

```
sudo apt install libmysql++-dev
```