# How to establish connection with database using MySQLConnectorC++?

Tags: c++, mysql, boost, c++14

I am trying to establish connection with MySQL database in C++ project.
And I followed the instructions given in [link](https://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/building-mysql-connector-cpp.html).
 After installing Cmake, I was facing problem in Build & Install MySQL Connector/C++.
Because `CmakeLists.txt` does not exists in directory.
After some search on web, I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31196510/1691223) and followed the steps given, but it didn't work in my case.

Frustrated will all this, I copied all the files(Extracted from [dowload link of MySQLConnector C++](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/1.0.html)) into my project folder, and trying to establish connection using this piece of code.

```
/* Standard C++ includes */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

/*
  Include directly the different headers from cppconn/ and mysql_driver.h + mysql_util.h
  (and mysql_connection.h). This will reduce your build time!
*/

#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include "mysql_driver.h"
#include "cppconn/driver.h"
#include "cppconn/exception.h"
#include "cppconn/resultset.h"
#include "cppconn/statement.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace sql::mysql;

void db_connection() {
    try {
        sql::Driver *driver;
        sql::Connection *con;
        sql::Statement *stmt;
        sql::ResultSet *res;
        /* Create a connection */
        driver = get_driver_instance();
        con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
        /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
        con->setSchema("test");

        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message"); // replace with your statement
        while (res->next()) {
            cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
            /* Access column data by alias or column name */
            cout << res->getString("_message") << endl;
            cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
            /* Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column */
            cout << res->getString(1) << endl;
        }
        delete res;
        delete stmt;
        delete con;

    } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
        cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
        cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
        cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
        cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
        cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

But it says, `undefined reference to`get_driver_instance'`, but it is defined in`driver.h`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have found the solution :)

First I completely un-installed `MySQL` from system `(MySQL Client, MYSQL Server and libmysqlcppconn-dev).`

After that, install all these again again.

1. Install MySQL Client and Server.
2. `sudo apt-get install libmysqlcppconn-dev`

Now ensure you have all dependencies installed

3. `sudo apt-get build-dep libmysqlcppconn-dev`

And now build the package using `-lmysqlcppconn`.